# Catalina Mail notification sound off sync

Tags: macos, mail.app, notifications

Since I use Catalina my Mail notification sounds don't work properly. They sound minutes or even hours after the new mail arrives.
Sometimes the sound rings at the moment I switch to an open window in Safari. Or back to Mail coming from Safari.
The issue appeared with the first release of Catalina, but is still there after several updates and a complete re-install (from the internet).

I'm on Catalina 10.15.5 on a MacBook Pro 13" late 2013. I just have one Mail account active.

Comment: It’s definitely not a PowerBook.  Do you mean MacBook Pro or Air?  Those are the only two models of laptop that had releases in 2013.  When you did a clean re-install, did you wipe the drive first?  Can you try this in Safe Mode”

Comment: Sorry, shure it's a MacBook Pro. I had so many Apple laptops in my life, can't keep up with the name changes. I did not do a 'clean' re-install. It would take me days to get everything in place again. Just re-installed the system, with the Apple apps.

Comment: Ok.  Try safe mode.  Second, before wiping your drive, try installing on an external USB flash or drive (need 32 GB or more; it only for testing).  Boot off that drive and try Mail.  If the problem goes away, the issue is with your OS

Comment: Seems a bit of a hastle, where it in fact is already clear that the problem is with my OS. The question is: how to fix it?

Comment: I font know how to fix a problem that we haven’t identified the cause of.

Comment: True.OK, in safe mode I do not have any sound at all on my laptop.

Comment: I'll try installing Catalina on an external drive.

Comment: So I installed Catalina on an external volume, booted from it and Mail notification sounds were fine. What to try next?